# Re encrypt using cryptsetup-reencrypt

Tags: cryptsetup

My LUKS disk is created some years ago the options would be outdated right now, if to change my LUKS header by:

```
# cryptsetup-reencrypt /dev/sdaX


WARNING: this is experimental code, it can completely break your data.
Enter passphrase for key slot 0: 
...
```

If I do it with a specific option, will the ignored options of cryptsetup-reencrypt use the default? like:

```
# cryptsetup-reencrypt --iter-time 3500 /dev/sdaX
```

And cryptsetup-reencrypt is designed for no data loss in regular situation?

Comment: `cryptsetup luksDump` of your existing LUKS header?

Answer (score 0):

> If I do it with a specific option, will the ignored options of cryptsetup-reencrypt use the default?

If by "ignored", you mean the ones that you don't pass, then yes.

> And cryptsetup-reencrypt is designed for no data loss in regular situation?

It's *designed* to not lose your data, but as the warning you saw indicates, it might lose it anyway. Make sure you have a backup before using it.

Comment: I guess I would bypass the most of options to avoid typo mistake. What's the secure cryptsetup-reencrypt options to LUKS? Does the secure options effect the speed of OS after login?

Comment: man cryptsetup-reencrypt  some options marked as warning,    WARNING: This is destructive operation. what about the unmarked?

Comment: In the context of that man page, ”destructive operation” means you won't be able to undo the effects of that command, so if you accidentally lock yourself out with one, your data is gone for good.

Comment: The effects of the different encryption algorithms are negligible once the system is booted, unless you have an extremely slow CPU and/or an extremely fast SSD.